# Can I have a Slideshow thats NOT fullscreen on Mac?

Tags: mac, slideshow

Is there something thats not key note or quicktime that will let me just select a bunch of pictures and play them in a window that choose the size of? I don't want to convert them to video files as the selection would change daily. Something like preview, but doesn't only play in full screen? Desktop user. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with the app [Phiewer](https://phiewer.com). It's free from the MacApp Store. When you start Phiewer it will ask you to locate the images. Then you can set the window size and then select slideshow. The window size stays the same and the images are displayed.